# Verify Lipschitz condition of $f(t,x)=t^3e^{-tx^2}$, $(t,x)\in [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Verify Lipschitz condition for $f(t,x)=t^3e^{-tx^2}$, $(t,x)\in [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$. I am having big troubles solving this problem. I'm using the formula
$\frac{|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)|}{|x_1-x_2|}$ and I get $t^3\cdot\frac{|e^{-tx_1^2}-e^{-tx_2^2}|}{|x_1-x_2|}$, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Why are you looking at that quotient? You want to show $|f(t_1,x_1)-f(t_2,x_2)|\le C |(t_1,x_1)-(t_2,x_2)|,$  right?

Comment: @zhw I am solving it like I solved previous examples.

Comment: What I wrote in my comment is the definition of Lipschitz on the given domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If you show that $|\nabla f(t,x)|$ is bounded on $[0,1]\times \mathbb R,$ then the mean value inequality gives you Lipschitz.

Comment: $\nabla f(t,x)=\left<3t^2e^{-tx^2}-t^3x^2e^{-tx^2},-2xt^4e^{-tx^2}\right>$. Now I need to find a maxima?

Comment: No, just show those quantities are bounded. This is not too hard given that $ue^{-u}$ is bounded on $[0,\infty).$

Comment: $\nabla f(t,x) $ is clearly bounded.

Comment: @zhw. But is boundness a necessary condition??

Comment: That will turn out to be the max value of $|\nabla f|$. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Alearner The domain is convex, so I believe it's an iff.